# How to escape equal sign for HTTP request?

Tags: powershell, http-post

In PowerShell I want to call something like this:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://localhost:3000/test" -Method POST -Body "a="
```

Note the body contains an equal sign (=), but in the server side (I'm using node.js+express.js), if I call `request.body`, it appears to be `{a:""}`, while what I want is `{"a=":""}`.

If I call something like this:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://localhost:3000/test" -Method POST -Body "`"a=`""
```

`request.body` is `"a: """`, i.e. a broken JSON string!

Comment: did you try using quote instead of double quotes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://localhost:3000/test" -Method POST -Body "`"a%3D`""
```

Answer (score 0):

Special characters in HTTP requests should be [percent-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). You could use a regular expression replacement with a callback to do this:

```
function ConvertTo-PercentEncoded([string]$str) {
  $re = [regex]'[^a-z0-9_-]'
  $cb = { '%{0:x2}' -f [int][char]$args[0].Value }
  $re.Replace($str, $cb)
}

$url = 'http://localhost:3000/test'

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method POST -Body (ConvertTo-PercentEncoded "a=")
```

or use the [`UrlEncode()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx) method:

```
Add-Type -Assembly System.Web

$url = 'http://localhost:3000/test'

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method POST -Body ([Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode('a='))
```